# How do I get the extras?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

How do I get any of the Social Club extras, like the Annis Elegy RH8? Yes, I am a member in the social club website, but the only problem is that I don't know how to get the stuff that comes with it.

Answer (score 0):

You bring up your phone by pressing up on the directional pad. Then go to internet. There you should find the cars on the car sites accordingly. Clothes will be in stores to buy. And finally, weapons will be on the far right hand wall of all Ammunation stores.